# INSERT INTO with subquery & parameters not working in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an INSERT INTO which works fine with the parameters as constants:

```
INSERT INTO FinalValidityCodes
                      (tblReceivedSamplersID, Substudy, Location, FinalValidityCode, DateTimeProcessed)
SELECT     ID, true, 'I', 0, now()
FROM         tblReceivedSamplers
WHERE     (SampleID = ?)
```

This would affect 1 row (as expected)

Yet if I change the query to use parameters it will allow it to run but will never affect any rows.

```
INSERT INTO FinalValidityCodes
                      (tblReceivedSamplersID, Substudy, Location, FinalValidityCode, DateTimeProcessed)
SELECT     ID, ?, ?, ?, ?
FROM         tblReceivedSamplers
WHERE     (SampleID = ?)
```

What is the difference and why, when I use parameters, does the Insert, seemingly, fail?

Edit:

SampleID is a text datatype.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting the syntax. I'm going by this example: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/sql-server-insert-into-with-subquery/. It seemed like in his query `INSERT INTO Orders (customer_id, order_date) SELECT id, GETDATE() FROM Customers WHERE username = 'john.smith'` GETDATE() did not need to be a column in the select statement but was rather to be inserted into `orders.order_date`.

Comment: I think the one of the link does work but it is very to think about why it is working. I like your way a lot better. It's much clearer where the values are coming from and what their role is in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the purpose of that INSERT is to add a single row to FinalValidityCodes with values for 5 fields.  However, 4 of those values will be supplied directly by query parameters, and ID/tblReceivedSamplersID will be derived from another parameter.

So I would try a DLookup() expression to get the ID (using the parameter for SampleID), and insert that value along with the other 4 parameter values.  Here is an untested guess.

```
INSERT INTO FinalValidityCodes (
    tblReceivedSamplersID,
    Substudy,
    Location,
    FinalValidityCode,
    DateTimeProcessed
    )
VALUES (
    DLookup("ID", "tblReceivedSamplers", "SampleID ='" & param1 & "'"),
    param2,
    param3,
    param4,
    param5
    );
```

Comment: I like this approach. The final working syntax was a little different than what you wrote but I edited it.

Comment: I approved the edit.  Thanks for doing that.  I assumed numeric data type for ID ... oops.  Sorry about the missing comma.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. This definitely was the right direction. Thanks!